# Run script once per browser session, but freeze script at end

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

I have a site in development [here](http://designedbyscott.co.uk/learning/tr/) and I'm happy with the intro. However, I need this script to run once oer browser session, and then to remain in its final state for the remainder of the session. Is this possible, or should I rearrange something. I'm pretty new to this and need a bit of help! My intro script is below:

```js
var words = ['websites', 'animation', 'branding', 'illustration'];
var i = 0;
var final = "thirdrail";
var splash = setInterval(function() {

  $("#word").hide().html(words[i++]).fadeIn(500);
  if (i == words.length + 1) {
    $("#word").html(final);
    clearInterval(splash);
    var time = setTimeout(function() {
      $(".overlay").addClass("level");
      $("#word").addClass("before");
      $(".logo").addClass("final");
      $("#static").html('<img src="symbol.svg"/>');
      $("nav").css('right', '-20px');
      $(".icon").css('right', '5%');

    }, 2000);
  }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Set a cookie...

Comment: You could possibly look into HTML5's SessionStorage, or if that expires too soon for you, LocalStorage. You can set a flag in either of these, and check for it when the page loads. If it has the flag, skip the intro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete example, if you need it

```js
var final = "thirdrail";

function startSplash() {
 var words = ['websites', 'animation', 'branding', 'illustration'];
 var i = 0;
 var splash = setInterval(function() {

  $("#word").hide().html(words[i++]).fadeIn(500);
  if (i == words.length + 1) {
   $("#word").html(final);
   clearInterval(splash);
   var time = setTimeout(function() {
    endSplash();
    localStorage.setItem("splashed", true);
   }, 2000);
  }
 }, 1000);
}

function endSplash() {
 $("#word").html(final);
 $(".overlay").addClass("level");
 $("#word").addClass("before");
 $(".logo").addClass("final");
 $("#static").html('<img src="symbol.svg"/>');
 $("nav").css('right', '-20px');
 $(".icon").css('right', '5%');
}

if(!sessionStorage.getItem("splashed")){
 startSplash();
} else {
 endSplash();
}
```

Comment: Perfect... Thank you

Comment: One quick question @br3t - the `endSplash` function doesn't include the array defined in `startSplash`... and the 'final' variable can't be accessed. Is it okay to just create another 'final' variable within the `endSplash` function?

Comment: I've made a little fix, try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies, or localStorage:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("intro"){
//go to normal page
}else{
localStorage.setItem("intro",true);
//show intro
}
```

Like Sam said while i wrote this...

Comment: They are pretty great! Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to Mozilla's SessionStorage page.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did have a little look at SessionStorage, but I can't figure out the best way to structure the intro. Because, the intro page animates **into** the header of my site. So, I need the script to be 'frozen' in its final state (the header), does that make sense? Obviously, for all inner pages, I can just create a fixed header, but not with the homepage...

Comment: You could possibly leave the script as is for people that haven't visited the page, but trigger a different one instead that goes straight to the end state if they have the SessionStorage flag. Ex: `if visited, trigger frozen; if not visited, trigger normal script;`

Comment: Ok, but youre ignoring the guys who disabled js, or have a very low internet connection (me). So i recommend you to hardcode the normal content into html, and if you show the intro moge the content to the intro state, and than let it fade back...

Comment: See, this is what I did initially, do you mean to just code a fixed header **as well as** the js version, and then fade the js version into the other? @Jonasw

Comment: What he is talking about is called Progressive Enhancement. It means that you would write a site that would work for a user with everything disabled, and then add things to it that would enhance the experience for users that _do_ have javascript, but aren't required to use the site. If I were to write a personal site, tbh I would say forget the ~3.6% that don't use JavaScript, but that is up to you. If it's business oriented you probably want to consider what 36/1000 bad site reviews could do.